# MVC Retrieving Data From DB and Displaying it in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not 100% how to tackle this.

I have a basic controller who retrieves data from a table called transactions

CONTROLLER
private NWBA_DBEntities db = new NWBA_DBEntities();

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var statements = db.Transactions.ToList();
        return View(statements);

    }
```

I have basic model:

```
public class StatementModel
{

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="Transaction Type: ")]
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "AccountNumber")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }



}
```

My problem is at the View, i cant seem to display the values in a table:

```
@model Login.Models.StatementModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Statements";
}


<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransactionType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
    <tr>

    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Can some one please help

Comment: you are not saving the values in the Statement model in the Action method in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var statementModel = from s in db.Transactions
                            select new StatementModel
                            {
                                TransactionType  = s.TransactionType,
                                AccountNumber = s.AccountNumber
                            }
        return View(statementModel);

    }
```